# How to find original value of x used in np.sin(x)?

Tags: numpy, time-series, trigonometry

I'm running functions to create cyclical datetime features, so I have converted timestamps to sine and cosine representations for ML model training.

In one sample, `x = 305.2116709309027`, giving `np.sin(x) = -0.459279` and `np.cos(x) = -0.888292`, my question is how to retrieve x from these sin and cos features later?

I assumed `np.arcsin(-0.459279) == 305.2116709309027` and I could then decode the timestamp used from there but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears that you really have a math question, not a programming question. It also doesn't meet the [minimum standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) for asking a question on Stack Overflow; you evidently didn't try [even the most obvious web searches](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+undo+sin+function) (where basically any webpage on the Internet talking about the arcsin function would tell you the important caveats), nor did you even try to explain what went wrong when you tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that mathematically, `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` are periodic functions, meaning multiple different values as input can yield the same output.

For example, `x=0`, `x=2pi`, and `x=4pi` can all yield the same value. So you can't decode the x from y, except you know that the input is restricted within a period, such as between `[0, 2pi]`.

HOWEVER, for `arcsin(x)`, since the domain of x is limited, and each y corresponds to a unique x, you can get the x from y.

[image: desmos graph]

Comment: Right I'm now realising how silly that question was, turning it into cyclical features removes the linear timeline I'm looking to retrieve, obviously. Think I just needed some rubber ducky debugging on this one (and more sleep!), thanks for the help!

Comment: haha, no worries. definitely get more sleep! :)